# Disk Device In Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows 10, you can [enable Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/). I have done this, but I am struggling to figure out how to access the disk devices. For example, in normal Ubuntu, if I wanted to do a low-level copy of one flash drive to another, I might execute `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4K`, but the `/dev/sd?` devices do not seem to exist in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. `lsblk` also does not list any devices. Since `dd` is installed, I would like to believe there must be a way to access disk devices. Can this be done? How?

[image: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows]

Comment: What did it say `cat /proc/partitions` (if it exists)? BTW you should find the mounted pendrive under `/mnt/f` if is f the name under window...

Comment: Doesn't exist. `cat: /proc/partitions: No such file of directory`

Comment: It seems it is not yet possible [Block devices, (i.e. /dev/sda) ? #689](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/689) at least following this comment of [27 days ago](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/689#issuecomment-262938882) it seems it will be difficult in future too. `:-(`... but maybe someone will find something different. Good luck.

Comment: I suggest you install `cygwin`. `cygwin` can access a removable Flash drive. I am using it now to execute `diff --recursive --brief /cygdrive/c/path /cygdrive/d/path` where "c" is the installed drive and "d" is the removable drive letter on Windows 10. Since this works cygwin `dd` would likely work.

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) doesn't install fully featured Linux kernel, only a stub that allows to run certain types on applications compiled for Linux. Btw. the *Bash on Windows* or any for of this name is incorrect (Microsoft mistake to name the command `bash`). I don't think Microsoft ever dare to add so low level access to the WSL.

However, from my experience what you want to achieve is available in virtual machine. In my case it was Ubuntu installed in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Then you can map USB devices to be available in guest system. That way `dd` commands are going to work at lowest possible level exactly like on natively installed Linux Distribution.